# Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct HelperConfig.NetworkConfig memory

Tags: solidity, struct, foundry, defi, stablecoins

Why even if I am returning a struct from a function then if I initialize another variable with the struct type it is showing me the following error:

```
Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct HelperConfig.NetworkConfig memory
```

Here's my code-

DeployScript code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import {Script} from "forge-std/Script.sol";
import {StableCoin} from "../src/StableCoin.sol";
import {SCEngine} from "../src/SCEngine.sol";
import {HelperConfig} from "./HelperConfig.s.sol";

contract DeploySC is Script {
    function run() external returns (StableCoin, SCEngine) {
        HelperConfig hc = new HelperConfig();
        HelperConfig.NetworkConfig memory config = hc.activeNetworkConfig(); // error shown 

        vm.startBroadcast();
        StableCoin sc = new StableCoin();
        vm.stopBroadcast();
    }
}
```

HelperConfig.s.sol-

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import {Script} from "forge-std/Script.sol";
import {MockV3Aggregator} from "../test/mocks/MockV3Aggregator.t.sol";
import {ERC20Mock} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/mocks/token/ERC20Mock.sol";

contract HelperConfig is Script {
    struct NetworkConfig {
        address wethUsdPrice;
        address wbtcUsdPrice;
        address weth;
        address wbtc;
        uint256 deployerKey;
    }

    uint8 public constant DECIMALS = 8;
    int256 public constant ETH_USD_PRICE = 2000e8;
    int256 public constant BTC_USD_PRICE = 1000e8;
    uint256 public DEFAULT_ANVIL_KEY = 0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80;
    NetworkConfig public activeNetworkConfig;

    constructor() {
        if (block.chainid == 11155111) {
            activeNetworkConfig = getSepoliaEthConfig();
        } else {
            activeNetworkConfig = getOrCreateAnvilEthConfig();
        }
    }

    function getSepoliaEthConfig() public view returns (NetworkConfig memory) {
        return NetworkConfig({
            wethUsdPrice: 0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306,
            wbtcUsdPrice: 0x1b44F3514812d835EB1BDB0acB33d3fA3351Ee43,
            weth: 0xdd13E55209Fd76AfE204dBda4007C227904f0a81,
            wbtc: 0x8f3Cf7ad23Cd3CaDbD9735AFf958023239c6A063,
            deployerKey: vm.envUint("PRIVATE_KEY")
        });
    }

    function getOrCreateAnvilEthConfig() public returns (NetworkConfig memory) {
        if (activeNetworkConfig.wethUsdPrice != address(0)) {
            return activeNetworkConfig;
        }

        vm.startBroadcast();
        MockV3Aggregator ethUsdPriceFeed = new MockV3Aggregator(DECIMALS, ETH_USD_PRICE);
        ERC20Mock wethMock = new ERC20Mock();

        MockV3Aggregator btcUsdPriceFeed = new MockV3Aggregator(DECIMALS, BTC_USD_PRICE);
        ERC20Mock wbtcMock = new ERC20Mock();
        vm.stopBroadcast();

        return NetworkConfig({
            wethUsdPrice: address(ethUsdPriceFeed),
            wbtcUsdPrice: address(btcUsdPriceFeed),
            weth: address(wethMock),
            wbtc: address(wbtcMock),
            deployerKey: DEFAULT_ANVIL_KEY
        });
    }
}
```

Both the function **getSepoliaEthConfig** and **getOrCreateAnvilEthConfig** return type is of NetworkConfig struct but when after importing I am using with the following syntax it is showing the above error

```
HelperConfig hc = new HelperConfig();
HelperConfig.NetworkConfig memory config = hc.activeNetworkConfig();
```

can somebody please explain why so?
I maybe doing very basic mistake but I am not understanding the reason behind this.